# Custom indent width for BeautifulSoup .prettify()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, indentation, code-formatting, pretty-print

Is there any way to define custom indent width for `.prettify()` function? From what I can get from it's source -

```
def prettify(self, encoding=None, formatter="minimal"):
    if encoding is None:
        return self.decode(True, formatter=formatter)
    else:
        return self.encode(encoding, True, formatter=formatter)
```

There is no way to specify indent width. I think it's because of this line in the `decode_contents()` function -

```
s.append(" " * (indent_level - 1))
```

Which has a fixed length of 1 space! (WHY!!) I tried specifying `indent_level=4`, that just results in this -

```
    <section>
     <article>
      <h1>
      </h1>
      <p>
      </p>
     </article>
    </section>
```

Which looks just plain stupid. :|

Now, I can hack this away, but I just want to be sure if there is anything I'm missing. Because this should be a basic feature. :-/

If you have some better way of prettifying HTML codes, let me know.

Comment: In answer to your side question ("WHY!"): HTML and XML tend to be very, very deeply nested, and I'm guessing the Crummy guys like 80-column windows. But you might want to post to the mailing list/group and/or file a bug requesting this feature (and, since the patch is pretty simple—and ramabodhi already pretty much wrote it for you—you should include it with your email/bug report).

Comment: It looks like someone submitted a similar patch against 3.2 to the mailing list a couple years ago. See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/beautifulsoup/B4qryJpJqpY).

Comment: "1-space indent looks just plain stupid. :|" - Thank you. This is exactly what I was thinking when I was searching for this issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I actually dealt with this myself, in the hackiest way possible: by post-processing the result.

```
r = re.compile(r'^(\s*)', re.MULTILINE)
def prettify_2space(s, encoding=None, formatter="minimal"):
    return r.sub(r'\1\1', s.prettify(encoding, formatter))
```

Actually, I monkeypatched `prettify_2space` in place of `prettify` in the class. That's not essential to the solution, but let's do it anyway, and make the indent width a parameter instead of hardcoding it to 2:

```
orig_prettify = bs4.BeautifulSoup.prettify
r = re.compile(r'^(\s*)', re.MULTILINE)
def prettify(self, encoding=None, formatter="minimal", indent_width=4):
    return r.sub(r'\1' * indent_width, orig_prettify(self, encoding, formatter))
bs4.BeautifulSoup.prettify = prettify
```

So:

```
x = '''<section><article><h1></h1><p></p></article></section>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(x)
print(soup.prettify(indent_width=3))
```

… gives:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <section>
         <article>
            <h1>
            </h1>
            <p>
            </p>
         </article>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Obviously if you want to patch `Tag.prettify` as well as `BeautifulSoup.prettify`, you have to do the same thing there. (You might want to create a generic wrapper that you can apply to both, instead of repeating yourself.) And if there are any other `prettify` methods, same deal.

Comment: breaks on `<pre>`

Comment: `return re.sub(r'\n(\s+)', r'\n{}'.format(r"\1"*indent_width), orig_prettify(...))` with python 3.9

Answer (score 13):

Beautiful Soup has [output formatters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters). `bs4.formatter.HTMLFormatter` allows to specify `indent`.

```py
>>> import bs4
>>> s = '<section><article><h1></h1><p></p></article></section>'
>>> formatter = bs4.formatter.HTMLFormatter(indent=2)
>>> print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser').prettify(formatter=formatter))
<section>
  <article>
    <h1>
    </h1>
    <p>
    </p>
  </article>
</section>
```

You can also use it from command-line with [pyfil](https://pypi.org/project/pyfil/) (e.g. to integrate with Geany's "Send Selection to" feature):

```
pyfil 'bs4.BeautifulSoup(stdin, "html.parser").prettify(formatter=bs4.formatter.HTMLFormatter(indent=2))'
```

Comment: I get the following error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'indent'`. I've searched far and wide across the internet but nothing came of it.

Comment: You must be using an old version of the package. `indent` was added in [this commit](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/revision/629). According to the [changelog](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/CHANGELOG) it's released since version 4.11.0.

Comment: Turns out `pip install` does not automatically upgrade to the latest versions if the package is already installed. `pip install -U` is needed for this job. Thanks @saaj

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, this feature is not built in, as there are a handful of solutions out there for this problem.

Assuming you are using BeautifulSoup 4, here are the solutions I came up with

Hardcode it in. This requires minimal changes, this is fine if you don't need the indent to be different in different circumstances:

```
myTab = 4 # add this
if pretty_print:
   # space = (' ' * (indent_level - 1))
    space = (' ' * (indent_level - myTab))
    #indent_contents = indent_level + 1
    indent_contents = indent_level + myTab
```

Another problem with the previous solution is that the text content wont be indented entirely consistently, but attractively, still.  If you need a more flexible/consistent solution, you can just modify the class.

Find the prettify function and modify it as such (it is located in the Tag class in element.py):

```
#Add the myTab keyword to the functions parameters (or whatever you want to call it), set it to your preferred default.
def prettify(self, encoding=None, formatter="minimal", myTab=2): 
    Tag.myTab= myTab # add a reference to it in the Tag class
    if encoding is None:
        return self.decode(True, formatter=formatter)
    else:
        return self.encode(encoding, True, formatter=formatter)
```

And then scroll up to the decode method in the Tag class and make the following changes:

```
if pretty_print:
    #space = (' ' * (indent_level - 1))
    space = (' ' * (indent_level - Tag.myTab))
    #indent_contents = indent_level + Tag.myTab 
    indent_contents = indent_level + Tag.myTab
```

Then go to the decode_contents method in the Tag class and make these changes:

```
#s.append(" " * (indent_level - 1))
s.append(" " * (indent_level - Tag.myTab))
```

Now BeautifulSoup('<root><child><desc>Text</desc></child></root>').prettify(myTab=4) will return:

```
<root>
    <child>
        <desc>
            Text
        </desc>
    </child>
</root>
```

**No need to patch BeautifulSoup class as it inherits the Tag class.  Patching Tag class is sufficient enough to achieve the goal.

Comment: This should be very easy to convert into a patch against the bs4 source tree, which is handy. The OP can just make his own fork of the bzr tree and patch it, submit the patch upstream, etc.

Comment: Thanks guys. I just couldn't believe only one person had a problem with this in these years and proposed a patch, and it is still not merged. I have already modified the function to take variable length(as I hate hard coding things). It pretty much does what you have suggested. But the thing is you need to provide something for `indent_level` because of this line `pretty_print = (indent_level is not None)` And as I see the default value of `indent_level` is `None` and there is no dynamic way to change it. <_<

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to increase indentation w/o meddling with original functions, etc. Create the following function:

```
# Increase indentation of 'text' by 'n' spaces
def add_indent(text,n):
  sp = " "*n
  lsep = chr(10) if text.find(chr(13)) == -1 else chr(13)+chr(10)
  lines = text.split(lsep)
  for i in range(len(lines)):
    spacediff = len(lines[i]) - len(lines[i].lstrip())
    if spacediff: lines[i] = sp*spacediff + lines[i] 
  return lsep.join(lines)
```

Then convert the text you obtained using the above function:

```
x = '''<section><article><h1></h1><p></p></article></section>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')  # I don't know if you need 'html.parser'
text = soup.prettify()                      # I do, otherwise I get a warning
text = add_indent(text,1) # Increase indentation by 1 space 
print(text)
'''
Output:
<html>
  <body>
    <section>
      <article>
        <h1>
        </h1>
        <p>
        </p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
'''
```

Comment: breaks on `<pre>`

Comment: @Mila Nautijus, `<pre>`???

Comment: yes, [<pre>](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=html+pre). whitespace must be preserved in pre tags