# Preserve Whitespace in Django Template When Writing to a File With BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, django-templates, whitespace

I have a script that adds classes to heading tags using Beautiful Soup.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('test.html'), 'html.parser')
heading_tags = soup.find_all('h1')
for tag in heading_tags:
    tag['class'].append('new-class')
with open('test.html', 'w') as html_doc:
    html_doc.write(soup.prettify())
```

This works well, but I would like to preserve the whitespace in the file when writing to it. For example, this Django Template:

```
<div class="something">
  <div class="else">
    <h1 class="original-class">Test</h1>
      {% if request.foo == 'bar' %}
      {{ line.get_something }}
      {% else %}
      {{ line.get_something_else }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Becomes:

```
<div class="something">
 <div class="else">
  <h1 class="original-class new-class">
   Test
  </h1>
  <!-- The formatting is off here: -->
  {% if request.foo == 'bar' %}
      {{ line.get_something }}
      {% else %}
      {{ line.get_something_else }}
 </div>
</div>
```

I also tried using `soup.encode()` rather than `soup.prettify()`. This preserves the Django template code, but flattens the HTML structure.

Is it possible to preserve the original file's whitespace when writing to a file with Beautiful Soup?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15513483/7832176

Answer (score 1):

While this is a hack, the cleanest way I found was to monkey patch `BeautifulSoup.pushTag`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pushTag = BeautifulSoup.pushTag
def myPushTag(self, tag):
    pushTag(self, tag)
    self.preserve_whitespace_tag_stack.append(tag)

BeautifulSoup.pushTag = myPushTag
```

In BeautifulSoup, `pushTag` appends certain tags (just `pre` and `textarea` in beautifulsoup4) to `preserve_whitespace_tag_stack`. This monkey patch just over-rides that behavior so that *all* tags end up in `preserve_whitespace_tag_stack`.

I'd urge caution when using this, as there may be unintended consequences.