# Ignore / skip tags when prettifying with BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

Is it possible to ignore / skip certain tags when parsing and prettifying an HTML-document with BeautifulSoup?

I am using BeautifulSoup to prettify HTML-documents with large embedded SVG-images. There is no need to prettify the SVG-images and all of their child-elements. As performance is critical for this application, I thought I might be able to save some runtime by ignoring / skipping the SVG-elements when prettifying the HTML, and just include the SVG-elements as they originally were in the input.

I am aware of SoupStrainer but it seems to do the exact opposite of what I need. I have also read many of the posts here on StackOverflow and elsewhere, and none of them seem to address this issue.

### Example

```
# Messy HTML code.
messy = \
"""
<html>  <head>
   <title>
   
       Some title</title>
    </head> <body>
<svg>Don't parse and prettify this!</svg>
</body> </html>
"""

# Prettify the HTML code.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
pretty = BeautifulSoup(markup=messy, features='html.parser').prettify()
```

Which produces the result:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Some title
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <svg>
   Don't parse and prettify this!
  </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note that the `<svg>` element has also been parsed and prettified by BeautifulSoup. Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to give an exact answer based on that little input - Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, bs4 doesn't allow for skipping particular tags; but you could write your own parser ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56683309/6146136)) and include or allow exceptions, or use [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) to replace the tags you don't want to parse.

First, list the tags you want to skip parsing

```py
skipTags = ['svg']
# skipTags = ['svg', 'script', 'style'] ## list all the tag names to skip
```

---

If you don't care about preserving the the tags, you could just get rid of them entirely.

```py
# import re
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for n in skipTags: messy = re.sub(f'<{n}\s*.*\s*>\s*.*\s*</{n}>', '', messy)
pretty = BeautifulSoup(markup=messy, features='html.parser').prettify()
```

---

If you want to preserver the tags, then replace them with comments and then replace the comment after prettifying. [**This can be significantly slower than just getting rid of them.**]

```py
# import re
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
cReps = []

for n in skipTags: 
    rcpat = re.compile(f'<{n}\s*.*\s*>\s*.*\s*</{n}>')
    cReps += [m.span() for m in rcpat.finditer(messy)]
for cri, (sPos, ePos) in list(enumerate(cReps))[::-1]:
    repCmt, orig = f'<!--do_not_parse__placeholder_{cri}-->', messy[sPos:ePos]
    messy = messy[:sPos] + repCmt + messy[ePos:]
    cReps[cri] = (repCmt, orig)

pretty = BeautifulSoup(markup=messy, features='html.parser').prettify()
for repCmt, orig in cReps:
    pretty = pretty.replace(repCmt, orig, 1)

print('<!--messy-subbed-->', messy, '\n<!--pretty-->', pretty, sep='\n')
```

Printed output of the last statement above, with the sample HTML in your question looks like:

```html
<!--messy-subbed-->
<html>  <head>
   <title>
   
       Some title</title>
    </head> <body>
<!--do_not_parse__placeholder_0-->
</body> </html>


<!--pretty-->
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Some title
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <svg>Don't parse and prettify this!</svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

**Note that** I don't know if either method will actually improve performance, especially when you consider how many more times it will be through the HTML string/s. You might want to look into https://thehftguy.com/2020/07/28/making-beautifulsoup-parsing-10-times-faster/

Comment: Thanks very much! I apologize for not replying sooner. You have several good ideas. Perhaps the most efficient would be a custom parser. I copied the code from the link you gave and did some timing experiments. It seems the custom parser is 20x slower than the normal BS4 parser and `prettify` function. Obviously this depends on the custom parser, but in this case it is very simple, so perhaps BS4 uses a fast C implementation, while the custom parser is in Python (?) I have upvoted your answer, but am leaving the question open in case someone has a better solution in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: Furthermore, it seems that what I really need is the opposite of the `parse_only` argument to the `BeautifulSoup` class. Something like a `parse_except` argument. That would be an elegant and probably also quite efficient solution. Perhaps that will get added some day.

Comment: @questiondude I actually didn't know about the `parse_only` argument (looks rather handy, thanks!). Have you considered using that? You could list all the tag names in the [w3schools HTML reference](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/default.asp), or collect all the names in some of these files with something like `tagsList = set(d.name for d in soup.descendants if d.name)` [and then remove the ones you don't want]....or does that sound too risky in terms of data loss?